# Given a DropDownList how to find associated "OnSelectedIndexedChanged" event Method Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a dropdownlist in my page, as Shown below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Logic Goes Here
    }
```

In Page Load, From Session Variable I will get DropDownList id as "DropDownList1". Based on this ID string I can get the Control, but not able to get the Event Name associated with it.

So How to find the Event Name of Control by knowing Control??

Thnaks in advance

Comment: If you are using AutoPostBack = true you don't need to specify events. Auto postback will run the correct event based on what happened in the postback.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to get it by Attributes.

```
string selected = EventDropDownList1.Attributes["onselectedindexchanged"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your asking here but the event can be wired up in two ways,

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Or in the page load part:

```
AddHandler DropdownList1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged
```

I know your question is asking to find the name of the event from the control name but you wire the event to the control. If you need to test which control fired the event i.e. you have the same code wired up to multiple drop down lists and you want to control the code flow based on the DDL ID then cast the sender to access it's values:

```
Dim id As String = CType(sender,DropDownList).ID
```

Hope that helps, if you can give more info I can perhaps give a more definitive answer.

Sorry answer in VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blow code:

```
Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoPostBack = true you don't need to specify events. Auto postback will run the correct event based on what happened in the postback.

So you don't need to know the name of the event, just create the event in the back end and autpostback will fire the appropriate code.